# Appdynamics instrumentation for Tibco - how to configure dynamically unique node name for each JVM

Tags: java, tibco, appdynamics, nodename

We are instrumenting java agents on Tibco. There are few JVMs ob each server and we are trying to configure unique node name (since which ever JVM starts first we get data only for that JVM).

We tried to add the following in the startup command in the tra file:
 -Dappdynamics.agent.tierName=%tibco.deployment% -Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=$HOSTNAME.%tibco.deployment%

which didn't work since $HOSTNAME was not translated.

We need to define this dynamically since at every tibco deployment the configuration is lost and if we indicate a specific node name we have to reconfiure every tra separately.
How can we get the hostname dynamically into the tra file so we won't have to redefine every JVM (and we have many) after every deployment ?

Regards,
Yy